# target mingw with cygwin

Tags: c++, testing, gcc, cygwin, mingw

I've tried building the [gtest 1.5](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) library for MinGW

Using MSys to configure and then make results in a lot of errors, most about Win32API

On their website it says mingw is not supported but in the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_5_FAQ#Can_I_use_Google_Test_on_MinGW?) it is specified that a user managed to build it for mingw from cygwin configuring like this:

```
./configure CC="gcc -mno-cygwin" CXX="g++ -mno-cygwin"
```

This configure fails for me when running a sanity check for the C++ preprocessor ... something about **"/lib/cpp"**.

I've tried a cygwin install with only mingw-gcc4 (4.3.4) and a cygwin install with mingw-gcc4 (4.3.4) and cygwin's own gcc (~3.4.4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the library could be smoothly configured and built with cygwin gcc (3.4.4) using the flags you have specified above. You should only validate that gcc-mingw, gcc-mingw-core & gcc-mingw-g++ packages are installed in cygwin. There is no need in mingw-gcc4

Comment: now (-mnocygwin for CC & CXX) it says that the C compiler cannot generate executables. Any idea why ?